# flutter format not accepted by pub.dev

Tags: flutter, dart, code-formatting, flutter-pub

In the score tab of a Flutter package on pub.dev, I get 10 points removed because of formatting.
Though, I did run `flutter format .` within the project root directory.
The file mentioned in the score tab was successfully formatted by the command.
Also, I did that after updating Flutter.

[image: flutter format score penalty on pub.dev]

It says that my file doesn’t match Dart formatter and that I should run the `flutter format .` command.

Here is the file in question:

https://github.com/lcuis/search_choices/blob/master/lib/search_choices.dart

Is there a way to know which part of the file is not complying?

Is there more to do than updating Flutter to update the flutter format tool?

Should I use another tool than flutter format?

Is there any other solution than just accepting a lower score?

```
Flutter (Channel master, 2.6.0-6.0.pre.82, on Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) 4.19.0-17-amd64, locale en_US.UTF-8)
```

Comment: I think it might be because the comments in your file extend the line length by a lot, if you look in the SDK comments you see they always breakline them so they don't extend beyond += 80 line length. They are very picky about that

Comment: i read something along this indeed here https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev/issues/3956 . However, the same long comment lines were passing the format test with previous version a bit more than one month ago. I will try this anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @Stijn2210 I just tried with no lines longer than 80 characters (even comments) and the result is the same. If only the report was giving some useful indication such as the problematic line(s). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah dart formatting can be confusing. Maybe it has to do with their standard linting settings? You could always try to look up the default dart linting settings to see if there’s anything there

Comment: @Stijn2210 I opened an issue on github: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/issues/1055
Thanks anyways for the linting hunch. Maybe this will come as the explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formatter version is the one mentioned at the bottom of the Score page:
[image]

In order to install a specific version of the `dart` sdk, I had to follow these instructions:
https://dart.dev/get-dart
Being on Debian and wishing to align with version `2.13.14`, I had to run:

```
apt-get install dart=2.13.4-1
```